# Satellite position computation using Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, python

my issue is related to the Runge-Kutta 4 (RK4) method and the correct iteration steps required for the state vector of an orbiting satellite. 
The below code (in Python) describes the motion based on the description as per this link (http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/GLONASS_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation):

```
        if total_step_number != 0:   
            for i in range(1, total_step_number+1):                             
                #Calculate k1                
                k1[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[0] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[1])
                k1[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[1] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[0])
                k1[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[2] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[2]

                #Intermediate step to bridge k1 to k2
                XYZ2[0] = XYZ[0] + (XYZDot[0] * h / 2) + (k1[0] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[0] = XYZDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[1] = XYZ[1] + (XYZDot[1] * h / 2) + (k1[1] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[1] = XYZDot[1] + (k1[1] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[2] = XYZ[2] + (XYZDot[2] * h / 2) + (k1[2] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[2] = XYZDot[2] + (k1[2] * h / 2)
                radius = np.sqrt((XYZ2[0]**2)+(XYZ2[1]**2)+(XYZ2[2]**2))

                 ....
```

There is more to this code however I want to limit what I show to this for now. Basically, for those familiar with state vectors and using RK4, you can see that the position and velocity is updated in the intermediate step, but not the acceleration. 
My question is related to the calculation required in order to update too the acceleration. It would begin for example:

```
XYZDDot[0] = ...
XYZDDot[1] = ...
XYZDDot[2] = ...
```

...but what exactly comes after is not very clear. Any advice welcome!

Comment: I don't know the precision you want to gain... but I'd start with Newton's gravitation.

Comment: Hi, basically the equation would be made up of the other vectors (XYZ is position, XYZDot is velocity). The quesiton is with what multiples of "h" and "k". A very random example would be: XYZDDot2[0] = XYZDDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2)

Comment: Acceleration should be an input for the RK loop, its  equations come directly from the physics of the problem, not from the integration of the values from the last step.

Comment: @N74, from the equations above, any ideas how this iteration step can be achieved?

Comment: As indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035696/satellite-position-computation-using-runge-kutta-4, your method is *not* RK4. If this is not your invention, please give a source. -- There is no updating the outside constants like the sun-moon force if the previous and next measurements are not known, or linear interpolation if they are known. You can not expect that a simplified model fits exactly the actual physics.

Comment: @LutzL: that is exactly the ponit with the updating of the constants of the acceleration (sun-moon force). My code doesn't at present acconut for this. The XYZDDot2 would therefore be implemented between the "k" calculations but it is not.

Comment: There is no updating, `XYZDDot` is a constant for the `[t-15min,t+15min]` interval.

Comment: Also, I would recommend a reference implementation using `numpy.integrate.ode` to separate the model errors from the implementation errors.